# Collections in the final projection must be an 'IEnumerable<T>' Consider using 'ToList' ... convert the 'IQueryable<T>' or into an 'IEnumerable<T>'

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

Since a group join query cannot be translated even in EF core 6, So I wrote the query as a Correlated Subquery. But I get the error:

"*The query contains a projection 'c => DbSet() .Where(c2 => c2.Country == c.Country) .AsQueryable()' of type 'IQueryable'. Collections in the final projection must be an 'IEnumerable' type such as 'List'. Consider using 'ToList' or some other mechanism to convert the 'IQueryable' or 'IOrderedEnumerable' into an 'IEnumerable'. , inner:*

The following Linq get me this error:

```
IQueryable<CoronaVirus> covids = context.CoronaViruses.AsQueryable();

IQueryable<CoronaVirusDTO> covids2 = (from c in covids
                                     let rt = context.CoronaViruses.Where(c2 => c2.Country == c.Country).AsQueryable()
                                     select new CoronaVirusDTO()
                                     {
                                         Id = c.Id,
                                         Country = c.Country,
                                         Date = c.Date,
                                         TodayCases = c.TodayCases,
                                         TodayDeaths = c.TodayDeaths,
                                         TotalCases = rt.Sum(it => it.TodayCases),
                                         TotalDeaths = rt.Sum(it => it.TodayDeaths)
                                      }).AsQueryable();
```

How to correct this Query?

Comment: I replaced AsQuaryable() in the let clause with ToList() and the produced SQL is still Efficient and It worked.

Answer (score 6):

The subquery must use ToList().
Don't worry, it won't generate an extra SQL for querying CoronaViruses.
It will be parsed into SQL WHERE as part of the linq expression.

Also, in the above example maybe you can use join.